# How can I supress output of a function only if it succeded?

Tags: bash

I have a function `get_value` that either does an `echo "$value"` or exits with an error message. I have a few other functions where I need to validate that the key exits. For that, I could just call `get_value`, but in case that the key exists, I don't want it to display the `echo`. How can I achieve that?

```bash
die() {
  echo -e "$@" >&2
  exit 1
}

get_value() {
  local key="$1"
  local value=
  
  value=$(awk ...)

  [ -z "$value" ] && die "Key '$key' doesn't exist."
  
  echo "$value"
}

remove_key() {
  local key="$1"

  validate_key_exists "$key"
  ...
}

validate_key_exists() {
  local key="$1"

  # Call get_value "key". If the key exists, then don't display `echo "$value"`, 
  # otherwise `die`.
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should stop returning values through `echo` and command substitution. Use a common variable instead like `__` and "return" values to it. You'll be able to calculate `$?` at  the same time.

Comment: Do you really want these functions to *exit* the current shell, or just return early?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump stdout from the function call to /dev/null.

```
validate_key_exists() {
  local key="$1"
  get_value "$key" >/dev/null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use command substitution techniques when returning values.

```
get_value() {
  local key="$1"
  __=$(awk ...)
  [[ $__ ]] || die "Key '$key' doesn't exist."
}

...

validate_key_exists() {
  local key="$1" value
  get_value key
  value=$__
}
```